# Getting nil resource URL when trying to read data file from XCAssets

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, xcasset

I am trying to read a video file saved as a data file in the XCAssets folder of my project. I am using the following code for this -

```
NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"login_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL: fileURL];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

This code had been working for me for quite sometime with target SDK set to iOS 8. I recently changed to iOS 9, and this now gives me a `nil` path and url.
The resource `login_video` is stored as a data file in my XCAssets folder. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

there are two way to get your url

first if you want useXCAssets

```
NSDataAsset *ob = [[NSDataAsset alloc]initWithName:@"a"];
   NSData *obdata = ob.data;
  [obdata writeToFile:@"your path" atomically:YES];
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"your path"];
AVPlayerItem *player = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:filepath];
```

second

copy the video to  mainBundle of your project and get it with

```
NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"login_video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
```

not in XCAssets folder.

Comment: Make sure the assets are members of your target; for some reason I noticed in an app that was failing it wasn't; not sure how but you should see a phase of "Compiling asset catalog" during build.